# how to redirect with https for particular page only in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i want to redirect particular page only to https, rest of page will remain in normal http.

i want to do this for payment page only.after successful payment site will run with normal http.

so please help me for do this.

i already try this one.

```
Route::resource('paynow', ['uses' => 'Account\PaymentController', 'https' => true]);
```

but this will not work for me.

Comment: If you already have a SSL cert on the domain, why only have one page secure? With how easy it is to get a SSL cert these days, there is no excuse to not have one!

Comment: @RobFonseca yes but its client requirement.

Comment: Ok. I would personally let the client know the proper way, but that is up to you. Is the server in a load balanced environment? Before I answer, that would change the way you do this if so

Comment: yes i already try this :).

Answer (score 2):

I would go about it by creating a custom middleware in **app\http\middleware** to intercept the request before it hits those routes.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SecurePayment
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->secure()) {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then add it to **app/http/kernel.php** in the route middleware group

```
/**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        .....

        'secure-payment' => \App\Http\Middleware\SecurePayment::class,
    ];
```

and finally wrap your route in the group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['secure-payment']], function() {
   Route::resource('paynow', ['uses' => 'Account\PaymentController']);
}):
```

Comment: Just realized I was missing a closing quote in the route group line. Just fixed it above

Comment: i already fix it before asking you. :(
But till got this error. Also changed : to ;  in last of route group.

Comment: Can you paste the error in here? The first few lines should work

Comment: 1.in ResourceRegistrar.php line 174
2.at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Array to string conversion', '/home/mandar/web/www.affnetwork.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResourceRegistrar.php', '174', array('resource' => 'paynow', 'controller' => array('uses' => 'Account\PaymentController'), 'method' => 'index', 'options' => array(), 'name' => 'account.paynow.index')) in ResourceRegistrar.php line 174
3.at ResourceRegistrar->getResourceAction('paynow', array('uses' => 'Account\PaymentController'), 'index', array()) in ResourceRegistrar.php line 246

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133984/discussion-between-vipul-patel-and-rob-fonseca).

Comment: I'm headed out the door right now. Won't be back online for another 2 hours. Meetings right when I get into work. The approach definetly works, but maybe a typo somewhere. I would lookup that error in the meantime